# Remove a single row in table created using div's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'v table which I create using PHP and I used divs to create the table, below is the table code.

```
<div class="limiter">
    <div class="container-table100">
        <div class="wrap-table100">
            <div class="table">

                <div class="row header">
                    <div class="cell topLeft">
                        Customer Name
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                        Target
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                        File Type
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                        Job Comment
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                        Cust. ID
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell topRight">
                        Select Job
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php while ($getJobsRow = $getJobs -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>
                    <?php $loopCount++; //Count the loop run through time ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell left <?php if ($numOfRows == $loopCount){ ?>bottomLeft<?php } //Set the CSS class if the loop is at the last row ?> " data-title="Full Name">
                        <?php echo $getJobsRow['customer_name']; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell" data-title="Age">
                        <?php echo $getJobsRow['Mal_Name']; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell" data-title="Job Title">
                        <?php echo $getJobsRow['FileExt']; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell" data-title="Location">
                        <?php echo $getJobsRow['Job_Comment']; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell" data-title="Location">
                        <?php echo $getJobsRow['customer_id']; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell right <?php if ($numOfRows == $loopCount){ ?>bottomRight<?php } ?> " data-title="Location">
                        <button class="selJobBtn w3-btn w3-blue-dark w3-round-medium w3-ripple" data-jid="<?php echo $getJobsRow['jId']; ?>">Select</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've select button for each data row. I want to hide or remove each row after data get successfully submitted to table. I use jquery to send the data and to disable the button.

My Jquery code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.selJobBtn').on('click', function () {
        var selBtn = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: '../Functions/OpenjobLister_Function.php',
            type: 'get',
            data: {
                'jid':$(this).data('jid'),
                'uid':$('#uId').val()
            },
            dataType:'text',
            complete:function(data){
                if(data.responseText !== "1"){
                    alert("Data not added");
                }else{
                    $(selBtn).prop('disabled', true);
                    $('.row').parent('div').first().remove();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I tried to remove a single line using many other methods mentioned in SO but none of them worked. Current code just removed the entire table I'm just stuck not knowing how to remove a single line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you find the parent div of any `.row` in your document, which is the entire table. Try to find the closest `div.row` from the button clicked and remove that one:

```
selBtn.closest('div.row').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML DOM elements to remove the row:

This is how you use the function where (0) is the index of the table row.

```js
document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(0);
```